# What is a good way to return a text field in a query for a calculated column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a members table on it. The columns on my table are first_name, last_name, date_dues_paid. I need to return a fourth column labeled active which would either be “true” or “false” depending on if date_dues_paid is a year old or more.

I’ve tried `CAST(WHEN ) AS active` and used DATEDIFF() and several other methods but just can’t get it right. I can provide more samples and code base later today, posting on mobile right now.

Comment: How are you storing your dates?  Can you include some sample data?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen they are Unix epoch time stored as int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one year to date_dues_paid and compare it against the current date like this:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    date_dues_paid,
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATE(date_dues_paid,'+1 year') > DATE('now') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS active
FROM members
```

Instead of TRUE/FALSE strings you could also use bool (1,0) as a result:

```
SELECT DATE(date_dues_paid,'+1 year') > DATE('now') AS active
```

Comment: This worked out well, I had to adjust my column to be an actual date (i.e. 2020-05-08) and add parenthesis around the nested select, but I ended up with this and it's working well:

`SELECT
 first_name,
 last_name,
 date_dues_paid,
 (SELECT DATE(date_dues_paid, '+1 year') > DATE('now')) AS member_active
FROM members`